# Java's JSpinner changes it's year wrongly

Tags: java, swing, calendar, simpledateformat, jspinner

This is how I created a date JSpinner. When I click on arrows, it can only decrement year by some value (two or one) or increment (only couple of times) by one. I am confused, please help!

```
Date current = calendar.getTime();
SpinnerDateModel yearsData = new SpinnerDateModel(current,null,null,Calendar.YEAR);
JSpinner years = new JSpinner(yearsData);
years.setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(years, "YYYY"));
JFormattedTextField tfYears = ((JSpinner.DefaultEditor)years.getEditor()).getTextField();
tfYears.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
tfYears.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 10));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `y` instead of `Y`

```
years.setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(years, "yyyy"));
```

`Y` = Week Year, `y` = Year

Read: [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)